# Getting auto-complete-mode user dictionary to work

Tags: completion, auto-complete-mode

I have been having trouble getting user-defined dictionaries to work with `auto-complete-mode`. I have read [the documentation](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html#user-defined-dictionary), and I have the following configuration in my init file:

```
(use-package auto-complete
   :ensure t
   :init
   (require 'auto-complete-config)
   (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/es-ac-dict")
   (setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
   (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'sql-interactive-mode)
   (add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-complete-mode 1))))
```

I only use auto-complete mode with `sql-interactive mode` and I have a file called `sql-interactive-mode` in the directory `~/.emacs.d/es-ac-dict` with the following:

```
select
where
from
```

However, when I am in a `sql-interactive-mode` buffer, my dictionary doesn't seem to be used. Once I type `select`, the next time I type `select` I will get a completion from `ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers`, but I don't get completions initially from my dictionary. Do I have the format of the file/directory structure wrong, or is it something else in my `auto-complete-mode` configuration? Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Here is [screenshot](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/syohex/fa55bf3b347ecdd28e09/raw/2e2e35536cf8b5e3a05f7eeaab3ba27d4d8a7522/ac-sql.png).  `d` is displayed at `select` line, it means completing from dictionary.

Comment: @syohex, Can you tell me the steps you took to get that result?

Comment: Launch Emacs with [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/syohex/fa55bf3b347ecdd28e09#file-ac-sql-el) same as yours, and  I input `select`. Gif animation is [here](https://gist.github.com/syohex/fa55bf3b347ecdd28e09#file-ac-sql-el)

Comment: @syohex thanks for the detailed recreation! It seems like something else must be going on in my configuration to prevent things from working right. One difference I noticed is that you are using sqlite, and I am using mysql, but I don't think that should make a difference in terms of completion.